# What does a “logo” means in sales/business talk?

Tags: terminology, business-language

At my company we use the term "new logos" in context of acquiring new customers, but I never heard it before so I googled and I could barely find anything except for this one article: [The Reason You’re Not Winning More New Logos](http://www.salesbenchmarkindex.com/blog/the-reason-you%E2%80%99re-not-winning-more-new-logos)

EDIT: Thanks for the explanations. I just wanted to add that in my company this term is used in very derived way, as in "we have a chance to logo here" or "we must prioritise, the client is a logo".

Comment: It's a reference to putting the logos of your clients on your web pages or promotional material. The more recognisable logos you display, the more reputable and successful you look. Winning new clients = using their logos (company names) in this way.

Comment: If they got me as a new customer, they wouldn't add anything to their presentation.  But if they got Apple as a new customer, you can be sure the Apple logo would be added to their presentation ASAP.

Comment: This is one of the many many things that drives me crazy about business talk.  It's a new customer, call it a new customer!  How hard is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"New logos" is the opposite of "existing accounts" or "current customers"**

Examples:

> How many **new logo accounts** do you need to land in 2014, how much
>   will you to invest to achieve your objectives, and what can you do to
>   get more bang for your buck?
>
> Landing **new logo accounts** is essential to the health of any business.
>   As hard as we try to maximize the potential of **existing accounts**,
>   there will be some natural attrition over time as personnel and
>   priorities change.

(http://blogs.richardson.com/tag/new-logo-accounts/?vid=null)

> They are focused exclusively on **new logo acquisition**. They are not selling to **current customers** and they are not managing relationships.

(http://www.salesbenchmarkindex.com/bid/58855/Go-to-Market-Strategy-The-Hunter-Misconception)

You can also search for "new logo sales" on Indeed.com, for example, to get more context: http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=new+logo+sales&l=

Answer (score 1):

When you see a Championship League interview, a player or a coach is being interviewed in front of a board with many logos of sponsorship companies. The more logos, the more financial support for the league.

When a company, especially financial firms, makes a presentation material, they put logos of their clients in the cover so that they can illustrate their capacity in dealing with very famous companies. The more logos of globally well-known companies, the more prestigious and reliable the company would look.

"[***Logo***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/logo)" simply means:

> A symbol or emblem that acts as a trademark or a means of
>   identification of an institution or other entity.

***New logos can mean new clients*** as you acquire the right to ***put their logos on your presentation or promotional material*** when you establish new relationship with them.